# Text to speech: Pause between comma

Tags: javascript, typescript, text-to-speech

I use tts, text to speech. I would like to add a longer pause after a comma. this.allTodos and this.allTodosTeam also contain some commas. Is there any chance to do this?

```
playMyDay() {

let text = 'Your day in 60 seconds: Your tasks for today, ' + this.allTodos + 'There are also some team tasks: ' + this.allTodosTeam

if (text != '') {
    this.buttonIcon = 'ios-headset'
    this.tts.speak({
      text: text,
      locale: "en-EN",
      rate: 1.4
    })
  .then(() => this.buttonIcon = 'ios-play')
  .catch((reason: any) => console.log(reason));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link to the lib that you're using.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/text-to-speech/